# Passando parâmetros Date para consultas

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, oracle, datetime, visual-studio-2017

Estou tendo um problema na hora de passar um parâmetro. Tentei depurar passando os `Date` como `string, mas surge o problema de que se espera um número em vez de um caracter.

Depois disso pesquisei outras maneiras e tentei passar os parâmetros do modo mais correto e tentar um valor do Tipo OdbcType.DateTime, mas ocorre um erro de conversão de valores falando que **'não foi possível converter um `DateTimePicker` para um `DateTime`'**.

Gostaria de entender os motivos dos erros e como posso solucionar esse problema para que possa usar os meus campos `Date` como filtro de consulta.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtaFinal.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        dtaInicial.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        txtEDV.MaxLength = 20;

        comboBanco.Items.Clear();

        List<Planta> plantas = new List<Planta>();

        using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Conexoes\Estados.txt"))
        {
            string linha;
            while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(':');

                var planta = new Planta();
                planta.Local = espaçoArquivo[0];
                planta.Banco = espaçoArquivo[1];


                plantas.Add(planta);
            }

        }

        foreach (Planta result in plantas)
        {
            comboBanco.Items.Add(result);
        }
        comboBanco.DisplayMember = "Local";
        comboBanco.ValueMember = "Banco";

        comboBanco.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void comboBanco_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmGrid formb = new FrmGrid();

        switch (((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local)
        {
            case "CT":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                break;

            case "CU":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                break;

            case "AT":
                formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection conn;
            string edvResultado = txtEDV.Text;
            //string date_inicial = dtaInicial.Value.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS");
            //string date_final = dtaFinal.Value.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS");
            Planta planta = (Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem;

            conn = new OdbcConnection(planta.Banco);

            MessageBox.Show(conn.State.ToString());

            conn.Open();

            MessageBox.Show(conn.State.ToString());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OdbcDataAdapter ada = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@edvResultado", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + edvResultado + "%";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_inicial", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dtaInicial;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_final", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dtaFinal;


            string sql = String.Format("SELECT * from emp where SSNO like '%{0}%' and LASTCHANGED between TO_DATE('@data_inicial 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('@data_final 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')", edvResultado);


            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            ada = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            ada.Fill(dt);

            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            FrmGrid c = new FrmGrid();
            c.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
            c.lblConexao.Text = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().SingleOrDefault(rad => rad.Checked == true).Text;
            c.grdRelatorio.DataSource = dt;
            c.grdRelatorio.Refresh();
            c.ShowDialog();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Acredito que `dtaInicial` é um controle. No comando que vai para o banco você está passando o controle inteiro (`dtaInicial`) ao invez do valor (`dtaInicial.Value`), como você fez no primeiro bloco de código. Tenta passar para o parâmetro `dtaInicial.Value` e `dtaFinal.Value`

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entende, e para mim tirar o comentário dos primeiros blocos e usar eles como parâmetro?, por que quando faço isso ele diz que espera um numero no lugar de carácter

Comment: Primeiro você precisa saber o que o seu componente `dtaInicial.Value` está retornando - pelo visto é uma `string`. Depois, você dá uma olhada no que o o seu parâmetro deve receber, eu acredito que seja um `DateTime`. Se for este o caso, basta converter o valor de `string` para `DateTime` na hora de atribuir o valor do parâmetro

Comment: Meus componentes estão retornando um Date DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00, tentei converter no parâmetro com dtaInicial.Value.DateTime, mas não deu certo e o DateTime se quer aparece como opção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no valor que está a passar para os parâmetros, que será um objeto do tipo `DateTimePicker` (ou algo do género) ao invés de um valor do tipo `DateTime`.

Altere o código para o seguinte:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_inicial", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dtaInicial.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_final", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = dtaFinal.Value;
```

Desta forma está a passar o `Value`, que será do tipo `DateTime`, do controlo para os parâmetros.

Esse não é o único problema, o comando SQL que está a passar para o `OdbcCommand` não está correto (pelo menos da forma como conheço). Experimente alterar para o seguinte:

```
string sql = String.Format("SELECT * from emp where SSNO like '%{0}%' and LASTCHANGED between ? and ?", edvResultado);
```

Se mesmo assim não conseguir que devolva resultados, faça o seguinte, remova a atribuição dos parâmetros e altere a consulta SQL:

```
string sql = String.Format("SELECT * from emp where SSNO like '%{0}%' and LASTCHANGED between '{1:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}' and '{2:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}'", edvResultado, dtaInicial.Value, dtaFinal.Value);
```

Atenção, esta forma não é a mais recomendada, porque estamos basicamente a fazer `SQL injection`.

Comment: Acabo de tentar fazer isso, mas o erro de que se espera um carácter não numérico continua

Comment: Resposta editada com algumas sugestões!

Comment: Foi uma boa ideia , mas no primeiro teste ele me retorna 0 linhas e no segundo o Objeto deve implementar | Convertible

Comment: De que tipo é a coluna `LASTCHANGED`? `Datetime`? `Date`?

Comment: Estava vendo aqui e a coluna e do tipo Date

Comment: E se utilizar a 1ª opção mas alterar o tipo para `OdbcType.Date` ao invés de `OdbcType.DateTime`?

Comment: Acabo de tentar sua ideia mas se eu faço isso e coloco Value = dtaInicial.Value, abre o grid e da 0 linhas e se não coloco "Value" aparece erro de Convertible, isso usando a 1 opção

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82468/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-gabriel-miranda).